# Issue implementing DNN Face Detector in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, ros

I have an issue running a face detection script using DNN Face Detector in OpenCV. I have read that the DNN Face detector was added with OpenCV 3.3 but I still can't run it.

**Specifications:**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- OpenCv 3.3.1-dev
- Python 2.7.12
- Ros Kinetic

**Error message:**

```
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/dnn/src/layers/convolution_layer.cpp:78: error: (-215) input.dims == 4 && (input.type() == 5 || input.type() == 6) in function finalize
```

**Code:**

```
import cv2

def main():
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(
        "deploy.prototxt.txt",
        "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
    )

    image = cv2.imread("acdc.jpg")
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Resources:**

- [deploy.prototxt.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1guR8prHbWcZba472j_alMBjD5mzStipW/view?usp=sharing)
- [res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17dYvaqc2ccjFbXFSUXu6WhMRUB9ewCj3/view?usp=sharing)
- [acdc.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hE0E7TfEi_vNpNrhh2gRyodWLZIUSWpM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your code runs without any errors on my system, which means you may have some issues with your OpenCV installation. Did you build it from source?

Comment: OpenCV was installed with ROS.